# How to export a PyTorch model to MATLAB?

Tags: matlab, pytorch, onnx

I have created and trained a model in PyTorch, and I would like to be able to use the trained model within a MATLAB program. Based on [this post](https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/607941-how-to-load-a-fully-connected-pytorch-model-trained-model-into-matlab) I have been exporting the model to ONNX and then attempting to load the ONNX model in MATLAB. I followed [this pytorch tutorial](https://pytorch.org/tutorials/advanced/super_resolution_with_onnxruntime.html) on how to export a model to ONNX.

However, I get this error

```
Error using nnet.internal.cnn.onnx.importONNXNetwork>iHandleTranslationIssues
Unable to import the network because of the following issues:

1 operator(s)   :   Unable to create an input layer for ONNX input #1 (with name 'input') because its data format is unknown or not supported as a MATLAB input layer.
If you know the input format, pass it by using the "InputDataFormats" parameter.
 The input shape declared in the ONNX file is '(batch_size, 12)'.
1 operator(s)   :   Unable to create an output layer for ONNX network output #1 (with name 'output') because its data format is unknown or not supported as a MATLAB
output layer. If you know the output format, pass it using the 'OutputDataFormats' parameter.

To import the ONNX network as a dlnetwork, set the 'TargetNetwork' value to 'dlnetwork'.

To import the ONNX network as a layer graph with weights, use importONNXLayers.

To import the ONNX network as a function, use importONNXFunction.

Error in nnet.internal.cnn.onnx.importONNXNetwork (line 37)
iHandleTranslationIssues(translationIssues);

Error in importONNXNetwork (line 113)
Network = nnet.internal.cnn.onnx.importONNXNetwork(modelfile, varargin{:});
```

Here is a minimal example to create the error

```py
import torch
import torch.nn as nn
import torch.nn.functional as F
import torch.optim as optim
import torch.onnx

class FFNN(nn.Module):

    def __init__(self):
        super(FFNN, self).__init__()

        input_size  = 12

        self.layer1 = nn.Linear(input_size, 24)
        self.layer2 = nn.Linear(24, 24)
        self.layer3 = nn.Linear(24, 12)
        self.norm1  = nn.BatchNorm1d(12, eps=1e-05, momentum=0.1, affine=False, track_running_stats=True)

        self.layer4 = nn.Linear(12, 6)
        self.layer5 = nn.Linear(6, 1)


    def forward(self, x):

        x = F.relu(self.layer1(x))
        x = F.relu(self.layer2(x))
        x = self.norm1(self.layer3(x))

        x = F.relu(self.layer4(x))
        out = self.layer5(x)

        return out

net = FFNN()
net.eval()

batch_size = 1
input_size = 12
x = torch.randn(batch_size, input_size, requires_grad=True)  # random model input for onnx
out = net(x)

input_names = ['x1', 'x2', 'x3', 'x4', 'x5', 'x6', 'x7', 'Qm', 'l1', 'uPre', 'basal', 'dG']
output_names = ['output']


# Export the model
torch.onnx.export(net,                       # model being run
                  x,                         # model input (or a tuple for multiple inputs)
                  'model.onnx',              # where to save the model (can be a file or file-like object)
                  export_params=True,        # store the trained parameter weights inside the model file
                  opset_version=10,          # the ONNX version to export the model to
                  do_constant_folding=True,  # whether to execute constant folding for optimization
                  input_names = ['input'],   # the model's input names
                  output_names = ['output'], # the model's output names
                  dynamic_axes={'input' : {0 : 'batch_size'},    # variable length axes
                                'output' : {0 : 'batch_size'}})
```

```matlab
nnMPC = importONNXNetwork("model.onnx");  % produces error
```

However I can validate the model in ONNX in python and it loads correctly.
So I think the problem is how I am loading it into MATLAB.

(my validation code)

```py
import onnx
import onnxruntime
import numpy as np

onnx_model = onnx.load('model.onnx')
onnx.checker.check_model(onnx_model)

ort_session = onnxruntime.InferenceSession('model.onnx')

def to_numpy(tensor):
    return tensor.detach().cpu().numpy() if tensor.requires_grad else tensor.cpu().numpy()

# compute ONNX Runtime output prediction
ort_inputs = {ort_session.get_inputs()[0].name: to_numpy(x)}
ort_outs = ort_session.run(None, ort_inputs)

# compare ONNX Runtime and PyTorch results
np.testing.assert_allclose(to_numpy(out), ort_outs[0], rtol=1e-03, atol=1e-05)

print("Exported model has been tested with ONNXRuntime, and the result looks good!")
```